# Javascript relative path

Tags: javascript, json, relative-path

In a first html file, I use a variable **categoryLinks** :

```
var categoryLinks = {
    'Career prospects':'http://localhost/Landa/DirectManagers/511-HelenaChechik/Dim01.html',
    'Compensation':'http://localhost/Landa/DirectManagers/511-HelenaChechik/Dim02.html',....
```

In a second html file, I am creating a chart by pulling some Json:

```
$(function () {
    var chart1;
    $.get('graphdata/Dim1.txt?x='+microtime(), function(json){
    obj = eval('({'+json+'})');
```

In this Json there is a line that refers to **categoryLinks** in order to point to the related hyperlink:

```
labels: {
formatter: function () {
return '<a href="' + categoryLinks[this.value] + '">' +
this.value + '</a>';
},
style: {color: 'blue',textDecoration: 'underline',fontSize:'13px'} 
}
```

},

All works well

I am trying to define the links in **categoryLinks** as a relative path and not an absolute one. I've tried unsuccessfully

```
var categoryLinks = {
    'Career prospects':'Landa/DirectManagers/511-HelenaChechik/Dim01.html',
```

Comment: `eval('({'+json+'})');` ... really? I do understand why you need to do eval, as you have `functions` in the data you're getting with $.get - but calling that data `json` is asking for (future) gotcha's

Comment: That’s not JSON but plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the URL of the page you're loading them into, which you haven't shown, but you may want a leading `/`:

```
var categoryLinks = {
    'Career prospects':'/Landa/DirectManagers/511-HelenaChechik/Dim01.html'
// Here ----------------^
```

...or possibly a leading `../`:

```
var categoryLinks = {
    'Career prospects':'../Landa/DirectManagers/511-HelenaChechik/Dim01.html'
// Here ----------------^^^
```

..or similar.

Basically:

Say you have

```
http://example.com/foo/page.html
```

and you have a relative link in it:

```
testing/stuff.html
```

That will replace `page.html`, giving you:

```
http://example.com/foo/testing/stuff.html
```

If you didn't want to be in `foo`, you'd either use a leading `/` which means "Start at the root of the domain":

```
/testing/stuff.html
```

...or `..` which means "go up a level":

```
../testing/stuff.html
```

The `..` can be used more than once, so if you have the page:

```
http://example.com/this/is/deeply/nested.html
```

the relative link

```
../../test.html
```

gives you

```
http://example.com/this/test.html
```

---

Also note that the links will be relative to the HTML page they're in, **not** the JavaScript script file they're in.

Comment: `Also note that the links will be relative to the HTML page they're in, not the JavaScript script file they're in.` - I think that's the source of the confusion in the question

Comment: Both pages are at the same level

Comment: I've tried var categoryLinks = {
    'Career prospects':'Landa/DirectManagers/511-HelenaChechik/Dim01.html'...    the issue is that whithout the htttp:// part, I don't get hyperlinks format